# Markov property for the gambler's ruin problem

Tags: markov-chains

Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be a simple asymmetric random walk  on states $0,1,\dots,M$, where $0$ and $M$ are absorbing. Initial state is $i\neq 0,M$. Let $(X_n^*)_{n\ge 0}$ be the process $(X_n)$ conditional on event $A:=\{X_m=M\text{ finally }\}$. That is $$P((X_0^*,X_1^*,\dots,X_k^*)\in B)=P((X_0,X_1,\dots,X_k)\in B|A)=\frac{P(\{(X_0,X_1,\dots,X_k)\in B\}\cap A)}{P(A)}$$ for any $k\ge 0 $ and $B\subset \{0,1,\dots,M\}^{k+1}$.

I need to show that $(X^*_n)$ is a Markov chain.

It's clear to me intuitively why it is so: on the event $A$ none of $X_k$'s should be equal 0, and then the Markov property is inherited from $(X_n)$, but I'm struggling with showing it rigorously.

Answer (score 1):

We can prove this by using the Strong Markov Property.
So, the Strong Markov Property says that ([Theorem 1.4.2 from the book Markov Chain, by Norris'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521633966)):

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$ be $Markov(\lambda,p)$ and let $T$ be a stopping time of $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$. Then, conditional on $T<\infty$ and $X_T = i, (X_{T+n})_{n\geq0}$ is $Markov(\delta_i,P)$ and independent of $X_0,X_1,...,X_T$,
where $\delta_i$ is the *unit mass* at $i$.

Now, we only have to prove that the time time to hit $M$ for the first time is  a *stopping time*.
The definition of *stopping time* is:

A random variable $T:\Omega\to \{{0,1,2,...\}}\cup\{{\infty\}}$ is called *stopping time* if the event $\{{T=n\}}$ depends only on $X_0,X_1,...,X_n$ for $n=0,1,2,...$.

Well, the time to hit $M$ for the first time is clearly a *stopping time*, since:

$$\{{T_M=m\}} = \{X_0\neq M,X_1\neq M,...,X_{m-1}\neq M,X_m=M\}$$

Therefore, $(X^*_n)=(X_{T_M+n})$ is a Markov chain.